# kubeadm init fails when using aws elb as control-plane endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

I'm trying to configure an HA kubernetes cluster within AWS, and I've been having no luck using an ELB for the control plane (right now an NLB with a TLS listener, but have tried with an ALB and HTTPS as well). No matter what I do, it always fails on the wait-control-plane step. If I bump up the verbosity of the output, I can see it curl my load balancer endpoint every second during this step, and after 4 minutes it fails out. There isn't any indication on what the response is from the load balancer, here's an example of the output I'm seeing:

```
curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.17.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/06ad960" 'https://<load-balancer-dns>:443/healthz?timeout=10s'
I0408 13:51:07.899477   27075 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://<load-balancer-dns>:443/healthz?timeout=10s  in 4 milliseconds
I0408 13:51:07.899497   27075 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
```

(There is nothing after response headers).

The odd thing is that while init is running, I can pull up that /healthz endpoint in a browser, which results in just a page saying "ok". I can also curl it from another terminal window and I get an HTTP 200 and everything looks good.

Further details - after init fails, there are no crashed docker containers. Kubeadm suggests checking the kubelet service status and journal, and I'm seeing lines like this:

```
E0408 14:50:36.738997   11649 reflector.go:153] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135: Failed to list *v1beta1.CSIDriver: Get https://<load-balancer-dns>:443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Curling that address does not give me any certificate errors, though it does give me a 403. The certificate should be trusted as it's chain is (I believe) imported correctly. So I'm not sure why kubelet is complaining about it.

The problem seems related somehow to the --control-plane-endpoint flag I'm using. *If I instead just let it default to the IP of the single instance*, `kubeadm init` will complete successfully and the cluster is initialized and I'm able to join workers to it, etc.

FWIW, my init command looks like this:

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "<load-balancer-dns>:<port>" --ignore-preflight-errors=ImagePull --apiserver-bind-port=30400 --v=10
```

What can I check to try to identify exactly what the problem is?

Comment: can you curl the LB endpoint from the VM where you are doing kubeadm init?

Comment: Yes, the DNS resolves, no certificate errors are detected. I can actually get the /healthz page back while init is running as well.

Comment: You curl the https LB endpoint right? The endpoint has self signed cert or external CA provided cert?

Comment: you have a egress asg open in the LB towards the master node VM?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine for traffic routing to the instance from the LB as far as I can tell. By running the same requests that kubeadm init is running, I don't see any issues.

Comment: Hey, I have the exact same problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @V1nc3nt - In our case, we had to update the SGs to allow IP-in-IP protocol (Calico needed it) - also made sure it was allowed in our NACLs. If you are using calico for your k8s networking, that may solve it for you.

Comment: @DanPotter Yes, I also found that out after many hours wasted, it was the same for us. Thanks for the response :).

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799078/9284676

When using ELB for your `--control-plane-endpoint` in a HA master scenario, you need to create a `Target Group` using type `IP addresses` and not `Instances`. The text is helpful when creating the Target Group:

"Facilitates routing to multiple IP addresses and network interfaces on the same instance."

I was then able to successfully init my cluster using this setup:

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "<myELBname>:6443" --upload-certs
```